# I can't see the option for contributing to twitter community notes, I was invited a while back

Tags: twitter

A while back I got a message from twitter inviting me to contribute towards community notes.

I have found a note that is lacking..

But I see no option to see or contribute to the discussion regarding it

Any idea where the option is?

Is it possible I lost the option by not making use of it when it mentioned it? I did indicate interest in it I think, when it offered it to me a while back. So I figured I had the option then and that i'd have the option now.

Comment: Here is some info [Locking and unlocking the ability to write notes](https://communitynotes.twitter.com/guide/en/contributing/writing-ability) as well as [Community Notes: Signing up](https://communitynotes.twitter.com/guide/en/contributing/signing-up)  and also  [Community Notes FAQs](https://communitynotes.twitter.com/guide/en/about/faq) There isn't much more we can help with.

Comment: it's not true that "only developers" can answer it
There are users of twitter that edit community notes and would know where the option is

Comment: The close categories are a blunt tool. Q references a msg that is presumably unavailable (email?). Q isn't  clear on what you received, when you received it, what you were asked to do, what actions you took and when you took them. Q asks users based on little info to confirm the possibility that not performing unspecified steps resulted in the option to take those steps being rescinded by X. The Q lacks details. The Q is likely to be answered with opinions and promote discussion rather than facts. X can rescind the privilege for stated and unstated reasons that only they can know.

Comment: Twitter is now X and it's not simply a name change. X doesn't describe a user outreach/recruitment program in the docs. Given the implied timelines it makes sense to start from the doc links that detail how to get and use the privilege and why it may not be available (regional user volume, user rep, phone # issues, etc.).  If the Q is based on a msg from X, the content, delivery method, timeline, etc. should be included. You can also use chat to discuss your problem with site users without the same content requirements.